# Disable navigation in Bootstrap header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple Bootstrap presenataion. I would like to have a clean first page,only,picture, without navigation bar. I want to show navigatin on next page(test1), so no navigation in HEADER. Here is my code for header and nav:

```
 <header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <div class="intro-lead-in"></div>
            <div class="intro-heading"></div>
            <a href="#test" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl"><img width="50" height="50"      src="img/start.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>



<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img width="100" height="50" src="img/logo.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#test1">Početna</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Som how to disable navigation from header section ?

Tnx a lot!
P

Answer (score 0):

for that page due to only wanting it for that page use an inline style to hide it...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: In that case, i hide nav on all pages...I need to hide just in header section

Comment: inline styles only hide the current page not all pages

Comment: But my content is on same page, on bootstrap template, so with inline styling, i hide nav on other section,too...

Comment: what inside the <nav> is it hiding that you dont want hidden?

Comment: I want to hide all nav tag. I just want flat picture on first screen. Then I will have button to scroll down on next section, and I want to show nav in that section

Comment: So you want the nav bar to be moved down and shown when the user scrolls down? because it does work.. http://jsfiddle.net/0um3poL7/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68366/discussion-between-pavlen-and-derrick-wells).